# How do I get Pages for iOS 7/8 to use the TAB key on a bluetooth Keyboard to change the indent level?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, pages

So Pages for iOS 7/8 has a software TAB key that changes the indent level of an outline. It also has forward and backward indent keys. Great.

However, when I press the TAB key on by Apple Wireless Keyboard, all it does is put in a tab character. The TAB key works fine on Pages for my MBP, with Shift-TAB back indenting it.

Is there a way to get the TAB key on the Wireless Keyboard to work like the software TAB key for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Apple would have to add an additional function for the bluetooth-users, which they hadn't until now. So it's not possible to use the tab-key, because you can't change the button-functions in the iOS-iWork-apps.